# Sqorus with rounded edges?

Tags: bevel

Seems sqorus was removed in blender 2.7.x so I used add mesh -> extra -> beam builder instead. How do I make this have rounded edges? If I add bevel modifier to it, it looks completely messed up.

[image]

This is what I want, smooth curves but cut straight in the front/back faces.

[image]

Comment: Just correct the normals before beveling (ctrl+N in edit mode)

Comment: Also adjust the *Bevel Width*

Answer (score 1):

Use the beam builder

Then in edit mode, select all and correct the normal <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>N</kbd>.

Now select one of the edges you want to bevel.

<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> to select similar and choose "length".

Your wanted edges are now selected.

Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> to bevel (use <kbd>Numpad +</kbd> or <kbd>Numpad -</kbd> to set the bevel depth).

[image]

Note: if you want to smooth it, click on smooth, but the result is weird, so, add an 'edge split' modifier.

[image]